# How do I find if an array has every element occuring twice except one OR an array with only one element occuring twice?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to solve the following kata : https://www.codewars.com/kata/583ef2456e39941f810001c5/javascript

Here's what I have attempted so far :

```
function countFrequency(arr){
    let  countMap = {

    };
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(countMap[arr[i]] == null){
            countMap[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
        else{
            countMap[arr[i]] += 1;
        }
    }
    return countMap;
}


function duplicateOrUnique(arr){
    let type1 = true;
    countMap = countFrequency(arr);
    let count  = 0;
    for(let key in countMap){
        if(countMap[key] >= 2){
           count+=1;
        }
        if(count >= 2){
            type1 = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(type1){
        arrSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
        k =  arr.length -1 ;
        return Math.abs(arrSum(arr) - (k*(k + 1)/2));
    }
    else{
        arrXor = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a ^ b, 0);
        return arrXor(arr)
    }
}
```

I have used `n*(n+1)/2` formula to find out the repeated element in case 1 while I have used XOR operation to find the only unique element. This process is supposed to be faster than the current solution. How do I optimize this?